# Region monitoring when device is off

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, cllocationmanager

I have a client requirement to monitor a region (say MyHome). To alert the user when he leaves MyHome and reaches back to the location. I can handle it pretty easily using the region crossing delegate methods:

```
locationManager:didEnterRegion:
locationManager:didExitRegion:
```

My question is, what will be the scenario if my device is off when I am at MyHome location. I leave the location MyHome, move to a different place and switch on my mobile. Will I get the  locationManager:didExitRegion: delegate method fired when I launch the app back and thus will be able to notify that I am away from the region. OR will I have to do anything else to get this possible?

Comment: When device is off, nothing works. The region monitoring delegate methods only gets triggered when you cross a region boundary while the device is on.

Answer (score 1):

First of all monitoring region is not made for such small area to monitor. You may not get actual results. Now, the answer of your question, yes. It is possible. When you will start your device, you will have delegates method to get hit.

Comment: Will you please elaborate? Which delegate method will be fired when the app is relaunched again?

Comment: If you have crossed the region, it will call locationManager:didExitRegion:

Comment: I dont think this is possible. It will not fire this delegate method once the device is switched on.

Comment: You should implement it and check. Since its mentioned in the apple docs, it must be possible.